# Layout composition / navigation with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection, caliburn.micro

So, I'm looking forward to create a simple layout in Caliburn.Micro, but I'm a little confused about how things are intended to be done.

The target layout looks something like this:

```
_______________________________________
|           |                          |
|           |                          |
|           |                          |
|    NAV    |          MAIN            |
|           |                          |
|           |                          |
|           |                          |
|___________|__________________________|
```

From what I'm reading on the many tutorials, there should be a root view model usually called `Shell` which derives from a `Conductor` and activates the `Main` view using `ActivateItem()`. So far, so good. But what if the `Nav` is itself a view, not just some stack panel with buttons? I tried the following:

```
## ShellViewModel
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>, IShell {

    private IScreen _navigationScreen;

    public IScreen NavigationScreen {
        get { return _navigationScreen ?? (_navigationScreen = new NavigationViewModel()); }
    }

}

## ShellView
<Window...
    <ContentControl x:Name="NavigationScreen" />
    <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem />
</Window>
```

The navigation view gets loaded perfectly fine. But now I've got a few questions:

- How am I supposed to signal e.g. the click on a button up to the `ShellViewModel` so it can change the `ActiveItem`? Through the `EventAggregator` (*really, broadcasting an event for all interested handlers just for a button?*)?
- Why does the view model (`Shell`) need to care about the layout? Wouldn't it be better to have some kind of router for composition/layout stuff?
- What about dependency injection? Let's say the `NavigationViewModel` needs a file reader because it loads (*I know, stupid example*) it's navigational items out of a file? Since I'm creating it myself in the `Shell`, I need to have a reference to that dependency where it doesn't even belong. Or is the `Shell` some kind of god class that holds reference to every dependency just to pass them to the independent views?

I'm unfortunately unable to find any tutorials on Caliburn that go further than just baby steps and simple view composition, but from what I figured out so far, it all seems tightly coupled with no respect for DI etc. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

DI is very available of course it is dependent on your container of choice, MEF, most samples feature it,  SimpleContainer (baked in).  There are Bootstrappers implimentations that are adapted for all other containers out there (StructureMap, Windsor, Ninject, etc), built in there is a static IoC class for getting to registered objects in the container outside of the bootstrapper, but I feel and some will say this as well that it has anti-pattern tendencies using it too much, use only when absolutely necessary.

To tell the views to switch for current actives, even though the sample is based on "dialogs"; Hello Screens does show how this is done cross viewmodel (ie shell to workspace) it is probably best answer to that bullet point

As for composition some will go with a custom conductor depending on the complexity you want.  I tend to go with KISS method and only separate out in to modules when I feel it's worth it.  `EventAggregator` is very handy for cross viewmodel communications.  if you intend to use composition of course `Conductor<>` is a good choice, view switching can also be implemented or a combination of `Conductor` and multi-view single viewmodel designs.

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>, IShell
{ 
   //INavigationViewModel is a "service interface" to the actual implimentation
   private INavigationViewModel _navmodel
   public class ShellViewModel(INavigationViewModel navmodel){

       _navmodel = navmodel;   

   }
} 

//can be done as long as NavigationViewModel is in the container of your choosing
```

Inside your NavigationViewModel you would probably work with something like `IConductor` interface that would tell the Conductor on the Shell that there is a new active item to process..

Just keep in mind that CM is viewmodel first primarily but does have the ability to do view first and is all in the configuration.. Choose one don't mix as a suggestion, mixing leads to weird behavior.

HTHs

Comment: Hello. Maybe I was a bit unclear with my question: I know everything can be done, they question is more: How is it supposed to be done in Caliburn? Take DI for example (I'm using Autofac): I've got a composition root (bootstrapper) where I configure all dependencies for all my services. My ViewModels are kind of services, so I want to have the dependencies being injected. If I want to composite my layout starting from the Shell, I have to either 1) inject all VMs in the shell and create a dependency graph or 2) refer to the static IoC instance. Both are undesired anti patterns which tightly ..

Comment: ... couple the code. And for the view switching: I was under the impression that with traditional mvvm, view compositions are a concern of either the views or a router. Caliburn feels akward in that way, so I felt like I was missing something. But yeah, I probably go with a custom conductor and take a look at the dialogs example, so thank you very much!